# More error info + longer program or less error info + shorter program?

Tags: python

```
def question():
    original = input("Enter a word: ")
    if " " in original:
        print("\n**Please only enter one word.**")
        question()

    elif len(original) <= 0:
        print("\n**It seems as though you did not enter a word.**")
        question()

    elif not original.isalpha():
        print("\n**Please only use letters.**")
        question()

    else:
        print(original)

question()
```

**VS.**

```
def question():
    original = input("Enter a word: ")
    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha() and " " not in original:
        print(original)
    else:
        print("**Make sure you enter a word, only use letters, and only enter single word.**")
        question()

question()
```

These two programs basically the same thing. But the top program is longer and gives more information on what went wrong when a user enters an invalid response. The bottom program is much shorter but does not give as much info for invalid responses. In real world coding, as in professional programming, which one of the programs would be preferred over the other?

Comment: You could probably use the bottom with simply "Enter a single word (using letters a-z only)", although you'll need to fix `original.isalpha()` - it's missing `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few exceptions (e.g. logins), more information is *usually* better (but this is highly subjective and specifics dependent).  That being said, we can improve your first verbose option a bit, for example:

```
# Allow multiple, simultaneous errors
def question():
    while True:
        original = input("Enter a word: ")
        errors = []

        if " " in original:
            errors.append("\n**Please only enter one word.**")
        if len(original) <= 0:
            errors.append("\n**It seems as though you did not enter a word.**")
        if not original.isalpha():
            errors.append("\n**Please only use letters.**")
        # if <another test>:
        #     errors.append(<test message>)

        if not errors: break

        # If we get here, there were some errors -- print them and repeat
        print("".join(errors))

    # We've broken from the while loop, the input is good   
    print(original)
```

Or

```
# Don't allow multiple errors
def question():
    while True:
        original = input("Enter a word: ")
        err = None

        if " " in original:
            err = "\n**Please only enter one word.**"
        elif len(original) <= 0:
            err = "\n**It seems as though you did not enter a word.**"
        elif not original.isalpha():
            err = "\n**Please only use letters.**"
        # elif <another test>:
        #     err = <test message>

        if err is None: break

        # If we get here, there was an error -- print it and repeat
        print(err)

    # We've broken from the while loop, the input is good   
    print(original)
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. Though there is one problem with the adjustments that you made. I actually ran into it myself. That is why there are no `while` statements in my current program. The `while` makes it so that you can't even input your response. It just skips over it.

Comment: is your while condition `True` -- in other words, is your line `while True:`?

Comment: Yes. I copy and pasted your code to see how it would work.

Comment: I also omitted the last line in your example, the call to `question()` -- you may have to add that back.

Comment: Now can you please explain to me how `if not errors: break` works? From my understanding, it is saying "if errors does not exist, then break".

Comment: The first (`if not errors:`) coerces `errors` to a boolean and in this case is basically equivalent to `if len(errors) == 0:`.  The second (`if err is None:`) checks whether `err` is still `None` after the processing (the error tests could set it to a string, in which case the test would fail and the loop wouldn't break).

Comment: Oh, ok. That makes sense. Thank you again!